# indexOf alike function in HIVEQL

Tags: arrays, hive, hiveql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    col1,
    case when array_contains(col1, "c") then "c exists" end as col2
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            array("a","b","c") AS col1 
        ) q1
    ) q2;
```

I want to check if the element "c" appears just before the element "b" in the array. In JavaScript I could use `indexOf()`, so if there were something similar in HiveQL I would do something like `case when col1.indexOf("b") = col1.indexOf("c") - 1`.

I have read the documentation, and it seems that the functions dealing with arrays are minimal.

I wouldn't like to split the array and check with `LAG` or `LEAD`.

I have tried with `field("c", concat_ws(',',col1))` but this seems not to work neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate array and use `like` or `rlike`. Example:

```
SELECT  concat_ws(',',col1) rlike 'c,b' as c_before_b_flag
FROM
        (
        SELECT
            array("a","b","c") AS col1 
        ) q1
```

Result:

```
false
```

`rlike 'b,c'` gives `true`

Comment: Thanks! not what I expected (I was really optimistic about a real index feature), but it worked. I can use `case when (concat_ws(',',col1) rlike 'b,c' = true) then 1 else 0 end as b_before_c_flag`. Still, the regex solution can help in case the logic changes a little bit, like for example if we allow 2 or 3 other elements between b and c (f.i b,x,y,z,c)

Comment: @agustin Use `case when (concat_ws(',',col1) rlike 'b,c' ) then 1 else 0 end`. = true seems redundant, rlike is boolean operator and `when` checks boolean